# export a csv file from the mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php"); 
    if ($_POST['frmCsv']) {
        $strSelect = doSelectCsv();
        header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv' );
        $strRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $strSelect );
        printArray($strRow);
        if ( $strRow ) {
            outputcsv( array_keys( $strRow ) );
        }
        while ( $strRow ) {
            outputcsv( $strRow ); 
        }
    }

    function doSelectCsv()
    {
        $strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member";
        $strResult = SelectQry($strSql);
    }

    function outputcsv( $fields )
    {
        $separator = '';
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            echo $separator . $field;
            $separator = ',';     
        }
    }
?>
```

This is my code to export a csv file from the database. but it could not select the datas. select query did not works correctly. please help me.

Comment: what does *SelectQry()* do? Write `return` on *doSelectCsv()*
also check [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Rather than write your own CSV writer, use PHP's built-in `fputcsv() function`

Comment: [Read the red box](http://php.net/mysql_connect) on each of the `mysql_*` pages: the extension is ***deprecated***. Don't use it anymore. Use the replacement(s): `PDO` or `mysqli_*` (where the `i` stands for _improved_)

Comment: i put select query to select the datas in the database. i put return on the function, but it cannot works sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it brother :)

```
<?php

if($_POST["download"]){ 
        $output="";
        $line_termineted="\n";

        if( $_POST["download"] =="CSV") $field_termineted=","; else $field_termineted="\t"; 
            $enclosed='"';
            $escaped="\\";

            $export_schema="SR No".$field_termineted."Student ID".$field_termineted."First Name".$field_termineted."Middle Name".$field_termineted."Last Name";
            $dataQuery=mysql_query("select * from sof_student ");
            $output.=$export_schema;
            $p=0;
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($dataQuery)) {
             $p++;
                $output.= $line_termineted.$p.$field_termineted;
                $output.=$enclosed.$data["id"].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
                $output.=$enclosed.$data["first_name"].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
                $output.=$enclosed.$data["middle_name"].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
                $output.=$enclosed.$data["last_name"].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
              }

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   if( $_POST["download"] =="CSV"){
        header("Content-Type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".csv");
    } else {
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=report".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".xls");
    }

    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $output;
    exit;
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `doSelectCsv()` doesn't return anything, but you have the following code:

```
$strSelect = doSelectCsv();
```

and then below:

```
$strRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $strSelect );
```

Without any knowledge about what `SelectQry()` does it's hard to really suggest a solution, but `doSelectCsv()` has to return a value to be used later on. Perhaps the following will suffice:

```
function doSelectCsv()
{
    $strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member";
    $strResult = SelectQry($strSql);
    return $strResult; // added this line
}
```

---

Note: The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

However, if we look at the MySQL code there is a problem with the following:

```
    $strRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $strSelect );
    printArray($strRow);
    if ( $strRow ) {
        outputcsv( array_keys( $strRow ) );
    }
    while ( $strRow ) {
        outputcsv( $strRow ); 
    }
```

You're assigning the first row to `$strRow` with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` but then you never fetch the other rows. I believe the above could should be something like this instead:

```
    $strRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $strSelect );
    printArray($strRow);
    if ( $strRow ) {
        outputcsv( array_keys( $strRow ) );
        while ($strRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($strSelect)) {
            outputcsv( $strRow ); 
        }
    }
```

This will send the array keys to `outputcsv()` for the first row, and then we loop through all the other rows inside that `if` block to send the rest of the data to `outputCsv`. But again, for a serious application, please do look in the newer extensions that PHP offers, because the `mysql_*` functions will eventually disappear.

Also, as someone hinted in the comments, PHP has a function write CSV data, namely [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/fputcsv). This will take care of any special cases (what if a data item has a comma in it?).

Comment: select query worked correctly. but there is no data will be fetched on mysql_fetch_assoc( $strSelect ) function.

Comment: @harikrishnan I've added to my answer to address the MySQL problem.

Comment: it selects my whole coding in the file. but it could not select the datas in the database

Comment: please give some alternations in the coding to export the file.

Comment: how to i use fputcsv() in this coding?... please help me.